# Jsoup : getting elements that not descend from a given type

Tags: jsoup

Let's consider that snippet :

```
<div>
    <img id="img1" src="my_image2.jpg">
    <a href="#>
        <img id="img2" src="my_image2.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
```

To get all the images not within a link (in this case the img with id=img1), the following selector `:not(a) img` seems to work.

Now let's consider that other snippet :

```
<div>
    <img id="img1" src="my_image2.jpg">
    <a href="#>
        <span class="my_class">
            <img id="img2" src="my_image2.jpg">
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

In this case, the selector mentionned above doesn't work and the two images are selected.
How can I modify my selector to make it work ? I'd like to avoid to iterate through the parents of the selected elements.

Thanks in advance

Koj

Thanks

Comment: Did my answer solved your problem? If yes please check it as the answer, if not, please provide an answer of your own and check that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific example this would work

```
doc.select("div>img:not(a>div>img)");
```

The not part is essential if instead of span you have a div inside of the a tag.
Here it makes no difference. This solution takes in mind what you want, and not what you don't want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. To be more generic we could even use `doc.select("img:not(a img)");`. What do you think? http://try.jsoup.org/~QMRj2b2EQe4S6gMSwl457Sh5g-Q

Comment: Well you have to make some decisions about the images you want. I mean, ok, you don't want them to be in 'a' tag. Is something else? You have to make a list of where you want them to be, and not where not to be. It's much easier and more generic